# Get Google Analytics account currency

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, currency

Looking through the API from Google Analytics, I couldn't really find an endpoint to get the account currency. Is there a way to do it, or does Google Analytics always return the currency in USD through the API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A Google Analytics account does not have a currency.

A view has a currency , and a transaction has currency. If the transaction currency is set, and is different from the view currency, GA will convert the revenue to the view currency (provided this is a known currency).

You can retrieve the view currency with the management API ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles)), and the transaction currency via the reporting API ([documentation](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/#ga:currencyCode)).

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Response already contains the currency and timezone from the api https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta

Reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/ResponseMetaData